# The string format of regular expression isn't working as expected with the actual one

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
console.log(/^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?)$/.test(22.22))

/^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?)$/.toString() // "/^(\\d{0,2}(\\.\\d{0,2})?)$/"

const intergerDigitLimit = 2;
const decimalDigitLimit = 3;

console.log(new RegExp(`/^(\\d{0,${intergerDigitLimit}}(\\.\\d{0,${decimalDigitLimit}})?)$/`).test(22.23)); //false
```

This is my regular expression `/^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?)$/`
I am trying to replace the digit limit dynamically with variable in JavaScript.
So I did this `/^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?)$/.toString()` to get the string format with all escape characters of expression so that I can change the value with a variable.

Output: `/^(\\d{0,2}(\\.\\d{0,2})?)$/`

*Replacing with variable*: `` `/^(\\d{0,${intergerLimit}}(\\.\\d{0,${decimalLimit}})?)$/` ``

*Actual regular expression*

`/^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?)$/.test(33.33)` Output: true

*Regular expression in string format*

`(new RegExp("/^(\\d{0,2}(\\.\\d{0,2})?)$/")).test(33.33)` Output: false

Why it isn't working after escaping the backward slashes in string format?
Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: What is "the digit limit"?

Comment: Accepted number of digits in integer and decimal part of a number

Comment: You need to use `.source`, not `toString()`. `/^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?)$/.source`. Please add your related code to the question to see how to best help you.

Comment: With .source function I got the right expression in string format where I can put my dynamic digit values to validate. 
Thanks Wiktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regular expression in JavaScript with slashes, e.g.

```
/^(\\d{0,2}(\\.\\d{0,2})?)$/
```

or from a string without slashes

```
new RegExp("^(\\d{0,2}(\\.\\d{0,2})?)$").test(33.33)
```

But you can't combine both, slashes in a string.

Example:

```js
console.log(new RegExp("/^(\\d{0,2}(\\.\\d{0,2})?)$/").test(33.33));
console.log(new RegExp("^(\\d{0,2}(\\.\\d{0,2})?)$").test(33.33));
```

Slashes in a string

```
console.log(new RegExp("/abc/").test('/abc/'));
```

are equivalent to actual slashes in a regular expression

```
/\/abc\//
```

Example:

```js
console.log(new RegExp("/abc/").test('/abc/'));
console.log(new RegExp("/abc/").test('abc'));
console.log(new RegExp("abc").test('abc'));
console.log(/\/abc\//.test('/abc/'));
console.log(/\/abc\//.test('abc'));
console.log(/abc/.test('abc'));
```